# unknown option in starting mongod using configuration file

Tags: linux, mongodb

command that i use to launch mongod

```
# ./mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
error command line: unknown option for
use --help for help
```

my configuration file

```
# cat /etc/mongod.conf
for=true
bind_ip=127.0.0.1
port=27017
quiet=true
dbpath=/data/db
logpath=/opt/mongo.log
logappend=true
journal=true
vvvvv=true
```

error info

```
# ./mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
error command line: unknown option for
use --help for help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first config file line says

```
for=true
```

I'm guessing that was meant to be 'fork'